# Issue with sorting array of strings using custom sort method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have following array:-

```
const a=["5.1.1","5.1.12","5.1.2"]
```

I want to sort the above to get the following:-

```
5.1.1,5.1.2,5.1.12
```

But if I call normal sort i get following.

```
 5.1.1,5.1.12,5.1.2
```

I tried implementing this using custom sort. Following is my code:-

```
let data = a.sort()
data.sort(function(x,y){
    const arrX = x.split(".")
    const arrY = y.split('.')
     if(parseInt(arrY[1]) >  parseInt(arrX[1])){
      return -1
    }
    if(parseInt(arrX[2]) > parseInt(arrY[2])){
      return 1
    }
})

return data
```

It works fine, but feels bit hacky. Does someone have a better solution for it?

Comment: Any solution will basically be the same, as `"12"` comes before `"2"`, and the only way is to split and convert to numbers

Comment: basically you need for every part  a check for the delta and if it is zero then proceed with the next part. if a value is different from zero, the return this value, or at the end zero.

Comment: thanks for helping out.. i was not able to put my query in words thats why could not find the already asked questions.. anyhow it helped and it works fine now @NinaScholz